# counting & loading correctly childrens from an xml file

Tags: php, xml

hello i have tried and nothing will happen...

i will count the childs from an xml file via php

everthing is ok but i dont get, - load correctly this stupid xml file into my page =

here's the script simply --

```
$url123 = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/ProJaCore/stats/GarrysMod/?xml=1';
$data123 = file_get_contents($url123);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data123);

$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($elem as $achievements) {
print $achievements->count().'<br>';
}
```

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_string($data123);` => $xml is already an instance of SimpleXMLElement ;)

Comment: You're double-converting. Once you do `simplexml_load_string` the variable `$xml` *is* a SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: o thankss ::) i am soooo blind haha x)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$url123 = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/ProJaCore/stats/GarrysMod/?xml=1';
$data123 = file_get_contents($url123);

$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($data123);

foreach ($elem as $achievements) {
    print $achievements->count().'<br>';
}
```

In your code you're creating a SimpleXMLElement object in `$xml`, then trying to create another one in `$elem` using the `$xml` object.

See the complete reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php